# Is ECMAScript engine not used by all browsers in Javascript for RegEx

Tags: javascript, c++, regex

Is ECMAScript engine not used by most standard browsers in Javascript for RegEx?
I ask this as there is a difference between the RegEx validation between that done at the browser and the one done in C++ at the back end both using ECMAScript standard(if I am right in saying that browsers use ECMAScript engine).

Reference to the C++ library I am using
[C++ regex lib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).
It has an option to use ECMAScript as the regex engine.
My understanding says thats browsers also use ECMAScript engine. But there are gaps between the validations done at the 2 ends.

For example - "\N" is an invalid RegEx in the C++ vesion. Whereas it is fine for the JavaScript counterpart. Same is the case with other non-escape characters i.e - Characters other than n,t,v,f,r,etc.

Comment: I thought Javascript had its own RegEx, but that it was the same in all browsers...

Comment: `C++` uses a slightly *modified* version of `ECMAScript` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript

Comment: And ECMAscript uses a subset of Perl regular expressions.